# Need to move heading over div

Tags: html, css

Need to move heading tag little left say 5px over the div. I have tried some solution but heading is moving but the content is disappearing .

```
<div>
  <div style="background: none;" class="taskdiv">
    <a>
      <img src="{{url+'/'+task.icon}}" class="img-fluid" />
      <h5 id= "heading" class=" text-center">{{task.taskname}}</h5>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

#heading {
left: -5px;
position: absolute;
word-break: break-all;
inline-size: 130px;
height: 50px;
}
```

I  have a div  which is like a rectangle box with a background color and a heading inside it, I need to move the heading a little left heading has a background color too so it will be like the heading box will be a little left of the div box like heading placed over div .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah just change the position to relative instead of absolute as absolute position break CSS default formatting context. "Run the code snippet below"

```css
.taskdiv{
margin: 0 50px;
}

#heading {
  background-color: red;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  word-break: break-all;
  inline-size: 130px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="background: green;" class="taskdiv">
    <a>
          <img src="{{url+'/'+task.icon}}" class="img-fluid" />
          <h5 id="heading" class=" text-center">{{task.taskname}}</h5>
        </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for a more in-dept understand of CSS positions https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: for some reason this is not working for me.. might be some other css issue in my side!

Comment: in my case the red box is going inside the green div not above the green div!

Comment: did you change the position from absolute to relative? 
@AmDGrtst

Comment: copy my code and compare it with your code @AmDGrtst also keep in mind that i added a left and right "margin: 0 50px;" to push the .taskdiv / the green-box away from the edges so that you could see #heading / the red-box better for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give x, y position so top: -5px and left: -5px or (some amount)

Then adjust the z-index so it will appear on top of the div
z-index: 2

Absolute positioning is useful for breaking the element out of the flow

Comment: left -5px i have given but heading is not moving over the div , it is moving inside!

Comment: updated, add z-index:2

Answer (score 1):

You just need to give the z-index for heading then it will show there too and make the positive relative for div like this

```
. taskdiv{positive:relative}

#heading {
left: -5px;
position: absolute;
word-break: break-all;
inline-size: 130px;
height: 50px;
z-index:99
}
```

second this you can try without position

```
#heading {
    margin-left: -5px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index:99
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm not exactly sure what you are talking about but I might know. I think what you are talking about is the margin in the html thats there by default.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Ok, let me explain, i have a div  which is like a rectangle box with a background color and a heading inside it, i need to move the heading a little left heading has a background color too so it will be like the heading box will be a little left of the div box like heading placed over div .

Comment: this will not solve the issue .check z-index andposition relative .